# Nodejs - How to acquire ID property whenever you change the value on a selection option object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

What I'm trying to acquire the is the value of _id whenever I select a value in my selected option object.

Currently, I was able to acquire and set the value of it's name but I'm getting a problem acquiring the _id as I need it to update the details.

```
<FormGroup className="mb-1">
    <FormLabel>department</FormLabel>
    <Form.Control 
      as="select" 
      id="create"
      value={department}
      onChange={e => setDepartment(e.target.value)}
      required>
        <option value selected>select department</option>
        {
            departments.map((deptname)=> {
                return (
                    <option key={deptname._id} value={deptname.name} >
                        {deptname.name}
                        {
                            setDepartmentId(deptname._id)
                        }
                    </option>
                )
            })
        }
    </Form.Control>
</FormGroup>
```

As you can see I am using useState from react. I set this setDepartmentId(deptname._id) but I'm getting this error message: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Could anyone assist and explain what's happening?

This is for my registration:

```
const Register = () => {

    const [departments, setDepartments] = useState([]);
    const [department, setDepartment] = useState(undefined);
    const [departmentId, setDepartmentId] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/departments/get-all-department`).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
            setDepartments(data)
        })
    }, [])

function registerUser(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/users/email-exist', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                // API only accepts
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: email
                })
            }).then(res => {
                return res.json()
            }).then(gatheredData => {
                if (gatheredData === false) {

fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/users/register',{
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            firstName: firstName,
                            lastName: lastName,
                            department: department,
                            position: position,
                            email: email,
                            mobileNo: mobileNo,
                            isAdmin: isAdmin,
                            password: "password123"
                        })
                      }).then(res => res.json()).then(convertedData => {
                       // console.log(convertedData) //true or false

                       const laman = {
                         method: 'POST',
                         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                         body: JSON.stringify({
                           email: email,
                           password: "password123"
                         }) 
                       }

                       fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/users/login`, laman).then((response) => response.json()).then(data => {
                            if (typeof data.accessToken !== "undefined") {
                              localStorage.setItem('NewUserToken', data.accessToken)
                              retrieveUserDetails(data.accessToken)
                            } else 
                            {
                              if (data.error === 'does-not-exist') {
                                Swal.fire('Authentication Failed', 'User Does Not Exist', 'error')
                              } else if(data.error === 'incorrect-password') {
                                Swal.fire('Authentication Failed', 'Password is incorrect', 'error')
                              }
                            }
                        })

                        const retrieveUserDetails = (accessToken) => {
                            fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/users/enroll', {
                                method: 'POST',
                                headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
                                },
                                    body: JSON.stringify({
                                    departmentId: departmentId
                                })
                                })
                                .then(res => {
                                    return res.json()
                                }).then(convertedResponse => {
                                    if(convertedResponse === true){
                                    Swal.fire({
                                        icon: "success",
                                        title: "Congratulations!",
                                        text: "Account has been created successfully."
                                       })

                                        setFirstName("")
                                        setLastName("")
                                        setMobileNo("")
                                        setEmail("")
                                        
                                    } else {
                                        Swal.fire({
                                            icon: "error",
                                            title: "Error message!",
                                            text: "Something went wrong, please try again later."
                                        })
                                    }
                                        })
                                    }
                    })

} else {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: "warning",
                        title: "Error message!",
                        text: "Email address has already been used!"
                    })
                }
            })
        }
}

}

export default Register;
```

Comment: can you share the full code of this file? I mean the full component

Comment: updated the problem is I dont know how to get the _id for the department. I mean, how to set it whenever I select a new option and set the _id to my setDepartmentId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your `onChange` method by following:

```
onChange={e=>{
 const value = e.target.value
 setDepartment(value);
 setDepartmentId(departments.find((x) => x.name === value)._id);
}}
```

Comment: onChange on a select tag you can get only option's value. But as you need both name and _id you can use only one of those as option's value. So you have to fetch the _id from the departments array.

Comment: Got it. Really appreciate it.